# How to modify a dom property in render.js based on other dom property in electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to modify a dom property say for example height of a particular div based on the value of another div.I have done like this but seems to be wrong.

```
win.webContents.executeJavaScript(
    `document.getElementById('div1').offsetHeight`,
    function(result){
        log.info(result);
        document.getElementById('div2').style.height = result + 35;
    }
);
```

I am very new to electron

Comment: Are you trying to make changes from main process into renderer process? If no and all your actions are contained inside renderer process, you could simply use javascript inside renderer process to manipulate dom almost as if you were inside ordinary web page

Comment: As I understand electron, `document` would not be available in the callback, and you'd need to do something like `win.webContents.executeJavaScript('document.getElementById('div2').style.height = result + 35;')` in the callback

Comment: Please, see [Electron Application Structure](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-architecture) for details about main process and renderer process.

Comment: @OliverRadini I tried the same but doesn't work.

Comment: @KshamaJain Do you get any errors at all?

Comment: @OliverRadini there are no errors .Also tried replacing ' ' with ``but no success.

Comment: can you try using `win.webContents.executeJavaScript("console.log('code running in callback')")` in the callback and check the console?

Comment: @OliverRadini tried that .looks like that particular line of code doesnt execute

Comment: Ok, could you replace `document.getElementById('div1').offsetHeight` with `console.log('initial code running')`?

Comment: @OliverRadini .looks like syntax issue ..replaced the code as you said no console logs logged.

Comment: @KshamaJain are you waiting for the window to be ready?

Comment: @OliverRadini did not perform dom-ready event.Will include that and try once